# API returns 429 error when fetched but works everywhere else

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, steam-web-api

So I am trying to fetch data from `https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/<USER_ID>/730/2?l=english&count=2000` USER_ID is replaced with a valid id but for privacy I removed it.

This is what my fetch request looks like in react and using axios:

InputField.tsx

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import style from './inputField.module.scss'
import { SearchIcon } from '../SearchIcon/SearchIcon';
import { ErrorMsg } from '../ErrorMsg/ErrorMsg';
import useAxios from '../../customHooks/useAxios';

export const InputField = () => {
  const [accountId, setAccountId] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [errorStatus, setErrorStatus] = useState(0);

  const err = {borderBottom: '2px solid red'};

  const handleSubmit = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!accountId) {
      setError('NO_INPUT');
      return
    }

    setIsLoading(true);
    
    useAxios(accountId)
    .then(result => {
      setIsLoading(false)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      setErrorStatus(err.status);
      setError(err.code);
      setIsLoading(false)
    });

  }

  return (
    <div className={style.formWrapper}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className={style.form}>
        <input
        style={error ? err : {}}
        className={style.input}
        value={accountId}
        onChange={e => setAccountId(e.target.value)}
        onClick={e => setError('')}
        placeholder='Steam account ID'
        />
        <button>
          <SearchIcon fill='#e0e0e0' />
        </button>
      </form>
      {error && <ErrorMsg status={errorStatus} message={error} />}
    </div>
  )
}
```

useAxios.tsx

```
import axios from 'axios'

const useAxios = (id: string) => {

  axios.get(`https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/${id}/730/2?l=english&count=2000`)
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })

  
}

export default useAxios;
```

server.ts

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import axios from 'axios';
import cors from 'cors';

import express from 'express';

const app = express()

app.use(cors())

const PORT = 3001;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);

  app.get('/api/getGameInventory/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {

    axios.get(`https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/${req.query['id']}/730/2?l=english&count=2000`,
    {
      headers: {
        withCredentials: true,
      }
    })
    .then(result => {
      res.send(result.data)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(err.response.status).send({
        message: err
      })
    })

  })

});
```

I am confused as to why when I call the endpoint I recieve 429 error even if the difference between each call is 30min. Postman too returns 429 error. I tried a online api tester and every one of those works fine and returns data without problem, and when I go to the endpoint in my browser I see data aswell.

I would really appreciate help with this problem and sorry if the question is bad Its my first time posting.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to post more of your code to show how you are using this in React, which can easily fire extra requests if not done properly.  Also, since this is working fine from a browser, I am guessing that possibly this API needs authentication and the browser may be passing that via cookies which your code above is not doing and postman would not as well.  To pass cookies, you need to do something like this:

axios
.get(
`https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/${id}/730/2?l=english&count=2000`,
{ withCredentials: true }
)

Comment: Thank you using {withCredentials: true} got me further, at first I didn't use this as the api worked but then I got 429 error again and after waiting 2h I tried adding withCredentials again and this time it showed 429 error from the call and when I accessed the api in browser. Something that I found strange was that withCredentials on it allowed me to view the page about 5 times after 429 error by clearing sessionId cookie but now again I have the 429 error and can't get rid of it.